# CSS rotating animation is choppy in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to spin an element on the page without spinning its children. Therefore I tried spinning them in the same speed in the opposite direction.
Animation works very fluid in chrome but when I test it in Firefox it becomes choppy after 1 time and consumes a lot of cpu power. is there anyway around this? Am I doing anything wrong here?

here is the link to [WEBSITE](http://admusicfuel.com/supermedium/index.html)

here is the [jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/B7vaJ/9/)

and here is my code.

**CSS**

```
   .circle-animated {
    -webkit-animation:spinr 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spinr 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spinr 20s linear infinite;

}
.inner-text-animated{
        -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear  infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 20s linear infinite; 
    }
.ch-item-animated {
    -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear  infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 20s linear infinite; 
}
.running{
    animation-play-state:running;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}
.stopped{
    animation-play-state:paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinr {
    from{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}


@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinr { 
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="circle-wrapper">
        <h1 class="logo">project<br/>..super<br/>medium.</h1>
        <div class="circle">
                        <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
                            <div class="ch-info-wrap">
                                <div class="ch-info">
                                    <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-1"></div>
                                    <div class="ch-info-back">
                                        <h2 class="inner-text">word.</h2>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
....
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
            // Animate loader off screen
            $("#preloader").fadeOut(750);
            $('.box-lid-menu, .box-lid').delay(750).animate({opacity: 1});
            setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.ch-item').addClass('ch-item-animated');
                    $('.circle').addClass('circle-animated')
                }, 1500)                    
});

$(function(){

//#Navigation
$('.box-lid-menu').boxLid();

//Rotation Hover
$('.ch-item').hover(function(){
    $('.ch-item,  .circle').addClass('stopped');

}, function(){
    $('.ch-item , .circle').removeClass('stopped').addClass('running');

    });
});
```

Any help regarding this matter will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle so we can try it in firefox?

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle lik

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@keyframes` instead `@moz-keyframes`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skuntsel I check my theory before posting answer.